# praw.errors.Forbidden: HTTP error when using Reddit get_flair_list

Tags: python-2.7, reddit, praw

I am trying to get the comments for each Reddit post.

This is the way I am using to get flair list:

```
import praw
import webbrowser

r = praw.Reddit('OAuth testing example by u/_Daimon_ ver 0.1 see '
             'https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/'
             'pages/oauth.html for source')

r.set_oauth_app_info(client_id='[client id]',
                 client_secret='[client secret]',
                  redirect_uri='http://localhost/authorize_callback')

url = r.get_authorize_url('uniqueKey', 'modflair', True)
webbrowser.open(url)
```

Then I got the code from the returned url, and I put the code in the access information, like this:

```
access_information = r.get_access_information('[returned code]')
```

Then when I am trying to call get_fliar_list() just like PRAW tutorial, like this:

```
item = next(r.get_subreddit('travel').get_flair_list())
```

It gives me an error, showing:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/praw-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/praw/**init**.py", line 565, in get_content
>       page_data = self.request_json(url, params=params)
>     File "", line 2, in request_json
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/praw-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/praw/decorators.py", line 116, in raise_api_exceptions
>       return_value = function(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/praw-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/praw/**init**.py", line 620, in request_json
>       retry_on_error=retry_on_error)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/praw-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/praw/**init**.py", line 452, in _request
>       _raise_response_exceptions(response)
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/praw-3.4.0-py2.7.egg/praw/internal.py", line 208, in _raise_response_exceptions
>       raise Forbidden(_raw=response)
>   praw.errors.Forbidden: HTTP error

Here's the link of that PRAW tutorial: [PRAW tutorial](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/)

Do you know how to solve this problem? How can I call get_flair_list() to get all the comments of a Reddit post?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things potentially going on here.

The first issue (And the most likely) Is that you are logging in wrong.

```
r = praw.Reddit('OAuth testing example by u/_Daimon_ ver 0.1 see '
         'https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/'
         'pages/oauth.html for source')
```

**DONT DO THIS, EVER**

Even if the syntax in this command was correct (you dont have the commas), this makes your code INCREDIBLY hard to read. The most readable way is to have `r = praw.Reddit('OAuth-testing')` (the `OAuth-testing` bit can be whatever you want, as long as it is the same as in your `praw.ini` file.), then setup your `praw.ini` file as such:

```
[DEFAULT]
# A boolean to indicate whether or not to check for package updates.
check_for_updates=True

# Object to kind mappings
comment_kind=t1
message_kind=t4
redditor_kind=t2
submission_kind=t3
subreddit_kind=t5

# The URL prefix for OAuth-related requests.
oauth_url=https://oauth.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for regular requests.
reddit_url=https://www.reddit.com

# The URL prefix for short URLs.
short_url=https://redd.it

[OAuth-testing]
user_agent=USER-AGENT-HERE
username=REDDIT-ACCOUNT-USERNAME
password=REDDIT-ACCOUNT-PASSWORD
client_id=REDDIT-APP-CLIENT-ID
client_secret=REDDIT-APP-CLIENT-SECRET
```

Just as an additional note, `get_flair_list()`  also requires moderator access, as documented [here](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/v3.4.0/pages/changelog.html#praw-2-1-13)

Also, you ask at the bottom:

> How can I call `get_flair_list()` to get all the comments of a Reddit post?

This would not be how you get all the comments of a post, if that is what you want to do you can read [this tutorial](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/comments.html#extracting-comments-with-praw) in the PRAW docs.

If you have any further questions don't hesitate to comment on this answer and I or somebody else can answer it!